# SSH Configuration between 2 new ubuntu servers

Tags: ssh, configuration

I am very new to the job and new to UNIX flavour OS like Ubuntu.

I have 2 machines, and I have installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS os on both of them.
 In both of them iI run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

After the above commands, I tried to SSH from one server to another by using IP address.
It's asking for my password, after entering the password, it's showing a permission denied error.

Kindly let me know the right procedure to configure SSH between these two ubuntu machines.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on using normal user/password login I don't think you need to transfer keys and it should work pretty much out of the box.

It's possible the sshd daemon is not started yet to give you time to configure. Try starting it with:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Do not use root to login, this is disabled by default.

From the client you should be able to login using:

```
ssh username@192.168.x.x
```

I full walk trough you can find here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring

Answer (score 0):

Define the ssh keys (used for the communication between the masters and slaves):
`ssh-keygen -t rsa`  (Use empty responses for each prompt)
`Enter passphrase` (empty for no passphrase):
`Enter same passphrase again:`
`Your identification has been saved in: /home/user-name/.ssh/id_rsa`

Your public key has been saved in `/home/user-name/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

`cd /home/user-name/.ssh`
`cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys`
Note: You need to copy the authorized_keys file into the corresponding .ssh folder of each node.
And then you are done. Now you can `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not asking your password on the client machine. It is asking the user's password on the remote (server) machine. You must enter the remote user's password.

Comment: Normally you should enter a password at the client side, not the server side. If the setup is using ssl keys you could have to enter a password on the server side but this is not the default setup.

Comment: You enter the password at the client side but you enter remote user's password.

Answer (score 0):

In order to Do SSH from one Ubuntu server to another,  we have to copy `id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys`.

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

or

```
cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
```

Copy the content of authorized keys to another server and we are good to do ssh.

Comment: The `cp` command will overwrite an existing `authorized_keys` file. Probably not what you want.